# If I'm [baldness-balding-bald], does it not mean that I have [hairloss]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just happened to come along [this question](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/11289/is-the-regrow-hair-protocol-by-david-mckenna-legitimate), which is tagged as both [baldness-balding-bald](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldness-balding-bald) and [hairloss](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hairloss).

I could've just gone ahead and retagged the former; it only contains six questions, but I see I should ask first:

- Are the two tags not referring to the same thing thus making one of them redundant?
- If they *are* different, what's the difference?
- If they're the same, which tag should go? I vote [baldness-balding-bald](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldness-balding-bald).