# Why hyphenated tags and not synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-management

I am curious why the [male-men-man-boy](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male-men-man-boy) is used and not making them all synonyms of [male](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/male)? Was this approach discussed somewhere?

Comment: Another example is [tag:baldness-balding-bald]
 which was [discussed here](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/688), to the extent that things get discussed here.

Comment: **Voting** *to make them all synonyms of male*. There are so many hyphenated tags, could we please update the Community wiki for all of them and declare them as synonyms?

Comment: As a reaction in your proposal: https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/717/8212

Comment: As a side note, ([meta-tag:tags]) and ([meta-tag:tag-synonyms]) (and perhaps also ([meta-tag:tag-management])) seem like reasonable tags for this meta question.