# Tag Wiki Marathon

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-management, retagging

**Update**:
[The whole month of Juli will be the time span.](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/731/8212)

---

### The motto: *Re-Tagging and Tag Wiki*

**It would be great if you could just reply in the comments if you're participating** so that we all can asses whether it is worth starting the campaign or too little users are engaging.

There are many tag wikis that are empty. At the same time, many tags are hyphenated synonyms (men-male-boy) as [discussed](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/688/8212) in [earlier questions](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/716/8212).

I'm therefore trying to **set up a Tag Wiki Edit Marathon (in the lack of a cooler name), where we give ourselves a week and try to update as many Tag Wikis and solve as many synonyms as possible**.

Obviously, especially the high-rep users are needed here because they can accept edits and rename tags. It might be best if they focus on accepting the edits so that we can do it smoothly. Furthermore, we can focus on burninating or re-tagging at the same time here in Meta.

I would strongly encourage you to post progress in this question.

Before we set out to find a date, **who will participate**? (There's no need to start if I'm all by myself).

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting idea, but I think 36 hours might be too short. Other SE (main) sites have challenges that last for a week or a month (literature SE, e.g.). Maybe that would be more realistic. I also agree that it needs a critical mass of users - not only higher rep ones. If there will be a lot of proposed Tag Wiki edits, perhaps higher rep users can focus on approving/rejecting while the rest of the community can work on actual writing. I'm not saying that users who can approve edits shouldn't participate in writing at all, but the more people join the more efficient the process with divided tasks.

Comment: I propose the whole month of Juli as a re-tagging and tag-wiki month!