# Tag wikis to be improved (or created)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-management, tagging, retagging

There are many tags without a wiki or hyphenated names. In the <s>month of July year 2017</s>, we will try our best to get rid of all these.

This way we ensure that no popular tag is left out.

Below is a list of tags used more than 25 times that should be renamed, burninated or need a tag-wiki

### Without tag wiki or insufficient wiki

- [tendons](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tendons)
- [tendinopathy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tendinopathy)
- [blood-tests](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood-tests)
- [blood-pressure](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood-pressure)
- [food-safety](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety)
- [research](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research)
- [stomach](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stomach)
- [smoking](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smoking)
- [risks](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/risks)
- [muscle](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle)
- [weight-loss](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-loss)
- [treatment-options](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment-options)
- [terminology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)
- [computers](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers)
- [bacteria](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bacteria)
- [food-supplements](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-supplements)
- [statistics](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)
- [lifestyle](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle)
- [headache](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headache)
- [topical-cream-gel](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topical-cream-gel)
- [coloration-discoloration](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloration-discoloration)
- [antibiotics](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antibiotics)
- [hair](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hair) currently lists hair-loss as one usage of it, but we already have [hairloss](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hairloss) and [baldness-balding-bald](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldness-balding-bald)
- [hairloss](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hairloss)
- [oral-health](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral-health)
- [injury](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injury)
- [mri](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mri)
- [virus](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virus)
- [nose](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nose)
- [health-education](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-education)
- [disease](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disease)
- [back](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back)
- [measurement](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement)
- [prescription](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prescription)
- [stress](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stress)

### Proposal to burninate / merge

- [treatment](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment)
  I just don't see how this tag will improve answers or add any important information, and we already have [treatment-options](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment-options)
- [effectiveness](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness)
  Again, this tag is not a meaningful categorisation of questions and should therefore be burninated.
- [baldness-balding-bald](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldness-balding-bald) because [hairloss](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hairloss) effectively covers all aspects of the former.
- [benefits](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefits) is too abstract in my opinion. What would a group of question with the Tag benefits have in common? Only very very little. **This tag is also lacking a wiki**
- [nutritional-info](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutritional-info) could be merged to [nutrition](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition).
- [time-of-day](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-of-day) I don't even understand what that one has got to do with Health and recent questions show that other users also tend to use it where it seems inappropriate (e.g. When should I take pills? Before or after meal? is unrelated to the time of the day in my eyes)
- [vision](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vision) and [eye](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eye). As of now, the tag wiki for eye also includes issues with vision. Most questions tagged with [vision](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vision) are also tagged with [eye](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eye) and vice versa. Maybe we either merge them together or merge them into something like [eye-sight](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eye-sight).

### Should be renamed

- [lasting-effects-duration](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lasting-effects-duration)
  It would be better to split this tag into `long-lasting-effects` and  `long-term-effects` as these are two totally different things currently combined in this ambiguous tag.
- [diagnostics](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagnostics) currently gets confused with diagnosis by many new users. This might be one reason why they think personal diagnosis is on-topic. Maybe a different name can be found for the tag. **This tag is also lacking a tag-wiki.**
- [myocardial-infarction-mi](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myocardial-infarction-mi) should be renamed to [myocardial-infarction](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myocardial-infarction). If we are going to include every abbreviation in the tags, they will grow. Furthermore, we encourage users to spell out acronyms once before using them as the post will be easier to understand this way. Having abbreviations as tags is counterproductive.

Comment: Consider making "baldness" (or similar) a synonym of "hair-loss", and "eye" a synonym of "vision", so that people who type the former will be routed to the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we can list the progress on the tags. Use the `<s>[tag:name]</s>` tags to cross out completed tags.

### Without tag wiki or insufficient wiki

- <s>[tendons](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tendons)</s>
- <s>[tendinopathy](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tendinopathy)</s>
- [blood-tests](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood-tests)
- [blood-pressure](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood-pressure)
- [food-safety](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety)
- [research](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research)
- [stomach](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stomach)
- [smoking](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smoking)
- [risks](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/risks)
- [muscle](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muscle)
- [weight-loss](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weight-loss)
- [treatment-options](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment-options)
- [terminology](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)
- [computers](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers)
- [bacteria](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bacteria)
- [food-supplements](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-supplements)
- [statistics](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)
- [lifestyle](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle)
- [headache](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headache)
- [topical-cream-gel](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topical-cream-gel)
- [coloration-discoloration](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloration-discoloration)
- [antibiotics](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antibiotics)
- [hair](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hair) <s>currently lists hair-loss as one usage of it</s>, but we already have [hairloss](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hairloss) and <s>[baldness-balding-bald](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldness-balding-bald)</s>
- [hairloss](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hairloss)
- [oral-health](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral-health)
- [injury](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injury)
- [mri](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mri)
- [virus](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virus)
- [nose](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nose)
- [health-education](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-education)
- [disease](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disease)
- [back](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back)
- [measurement](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement)
- [prescription](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prescription)
- [stress](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stress)

### Burninate/Merging

- [treatment](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment)
  I just don't see how this tag will improve answers or add any important information, and we already have [treatment-options](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treatment-options)
- [effectiveness](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/effectiveness)
  Again, this tag is not a meaningful categorisation of questions and should therefore be burninated.
- <s>[baldness-balding-bald](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldness-balding-bald) into [hairloss](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hairloss)</s>
- [benefits](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benefits) is too abstract in my opinion. What would a group of question with the Tag benefits have in common? Only very very little. **This tag is also lacking a wiki**
- <s>[nutritional-info](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutritional-info) into [nutrition](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition)</s>
- [time-of-day](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-of-day) I don't even understand what that one has got to do with Health and recent questions show that other users also tend to use it where it seems inappropriate (e.g. When should I take pills? Before or after meal? is unrelated to the time of the day in my eyes)
- [vision](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vision) and [eye](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eye). As of now, the tag wiki for eye also includes issues with vision. Most questions tagged with [vision](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vision) are also tagged with [eye](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eye) and vice versa. Maybe we either merge them together or merge them into something like "eye-sight".

### Should be renamed

- [lasting-effects-duration](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lasting-effects-duration)
  It would be better to split this tag into `long-lasting-effects` and  `long-term-effects` as these are two totally different things currently combined in this ambiguous tag.
- [diagnostics](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagnostics) currently gets confused with diagnosis by many new users. This might be one reason why they think personal diagnosis is on-topic. Maybe a different name can be found for the tag. **This tag is also lacking a tag-wiki.**
- <s>[myocardial-infarction-mi](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myocardial-infarction-mi) into [myocardial-infarction](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myocardial-infarction)</s>

Comment: The tags won't get crossed out.

Comment: @Narusan If you wrap the tags like `<s>[tag:name]</s>` and it should work

Comment: Take a look at the merged part: The tag is not crossed out

Comment: @Narusan It works [for me](http://imgur.com/a/sDXfJ).

Comment: I think I've just found a bug on the iOS App... Thank you for the merging and creating the answer section!

Comment: For some reason, I cannot create tag excerpts or tag wikis, I can only edit them. Could someone with the privilege create a simple excerpt so that I can update the tag wiki? I've worked on tendinopathy and tendon so far...

Comment: I suggested [tag:treatment] as a synonym of [tag:treatment-options]. Just need people to vote for the suggestion by clicking going to [treatment synonyms](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/tags/treatment/synonyms)

Comment: I think https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/14090/7951 is a good use of [tag:time-of-day] maybe